Wordpress search every time shows no search found even data exists
I am using wordpress. What I am doing is, that when the user enters anything then it will search from the post and will show the result.
I have added static content $_REQUEST['keyword']="team"; just for an example, Every time I get it No search found.
Any idea what is the issue?
function wpbsearchformOnly( $form ) {
   
    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" class="customform">
    <div class="search-field"> 
    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" class="universalSearchField"  autocomplete="off"/>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-search" ></button>
    </div>
    </form> 
    <div id="autosearchpost"></div>
   <script>
   jQuery(".universalSearchField").on("input", function() { 
     jQuery.ajax({
         url: "'.get_site_url().'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { action: "universalSearchlist", keyword: jQuery("#s").val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery("#autosearchpost").html(data);
        }
    });
    });

    </script>';

   
    return $form;
}
   
add_shortcode('wpbsearchformonly', 'wpbsearchformOnly');

add_action('wp_ajax_universalSearchlist','universalSearch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_universalSearchlist','universalSearch');


function universalSearch($atts)
{
    global $post;
    $_REQUEST['keyword'] = "team"; // it's just an example

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['keyword'])) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            's' => $_REQUEST['keyword'],
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );

    }

    //print_r($args);

    $result = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($result->have_posts()) {

        while ($result->have_posts()) {
            $result->the_post();
            $tid = $result->ID;
            echo '<p><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a></p>';

        }

    } else {
        echo '<p><a href="javascript:void(0)">No search found.</a></p>';
    }
    wp_die();

}

I am getting this SQL query.. something is wrong with query
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}leanding{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}leanding{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}leanding{a30a32c58212e0e69da1fe713200b690a215277638267d3fc914587e000d21db}'))) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE


How are you calling universalSearch()?

@ChrisHaas, i am uisng ajax.  I haven't updated that code. Only issue with search code

So you AJAX comes into an endpoint somewhere. Does that code call universalSearch()? Even if it did, that function isn't returning anything, nor is it modifying anything global that I can see, so I'm still not clear how universalSearch() is being invoked.

@ChrisHaas, I have updated the full code. Kindly check it once

Thanks, that helps, however it turns out that the formatting was what messed with me the most. I assumed that the closing brace with no spaces closed the function. I see now it is part of the if. The indentation is confusing.

For this, skip AJAX, just to test your PHP code. Have your short code just inline the query stuff, and hardcode a keyword. Once you get WordPress finding the data, then we can add AJAX back in. To debug this, after executing a query inspect it.

@ChrisHaas, Yes, I have tried and php code is working. I think there is some issue with SQL query..

I can tell you that the {a30a32... stuff is a placeholder used for escaping LIKE queries. It is added by add_placeholder_escape() which calls placeholder_escape(). The latter automatically registers a function to undo the escape. I can't say for certain why yours isn't firing however.

@ChrisHaas, I am not sure why i am getting {a30a32... stuff. You mean add_placeholder_escape() I am getting the {a30a32? but I haven't used it
